# How to handle tap events without blocking UI visualization changes in a listview

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, jquery-mobile

Using a jQuery Mobile button like:

```
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li><a data-role="button" href="#" id="test">Test</a></li>
</ul>
```

I am attaching a tap handler like this:

```
$('#test').on('tap', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.console.log('do something useful here');
});
```

The problem is that either `preventDefault` is blocking the JQM css changes to buttons like ui-btn-down/active/up/etc. or just adding the tap handler at all is preventing them. So it doesn't quite feel right to the user cause there is no visual impact of clicking the button.

Is there anyway around this problem? Perhaps manually assigning the classes in each handler - though that seems heavy handed.

Comment: have you tried ``return false`` at the end of the event?

Comment: yes, same as preventDefault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further testing, my premise for this question was wrong. The issue appears to be the duration of the tap itself. If you tap too quickly the classes don't get applied, but a few ms longer and they do. I am closing this question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of preventing default actions of a link, you can use the button element:

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <button id="test">Test</button>
    <br /><br />
    <input type="text" value="" id="output" />
</div> 

$('#test').on('tap', function(event) {        
    $("#output").val(new Date());
});
```

jQM styles the button the same way, so there is no real difference.

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/F48da/4/)**

Comment: That is a good idea and should work in most cases. However, as far as I know, you can't use `<button>`s in a listview - you have to use anchors...

Comment: I just updated the question to specify listview usage.

Comment: @maxmoore14, if you set href="#", why do you need preventDefault? Also, you can use vertical controlgroup to get a simple list of buttons: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/controlgroup/

Comment: On further testing, my whole premise for the question is wrong. Thanks for the help though!